# Insertar en la base de datos

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de insertar registros en la base de datos pero al ingresar por el explorador me envia a la direccion
`http://localhost/Vista/validarInsertarMedico.php`
y ese archivo esta en la carpeta Controlador

Tengo el formulario

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="../Controlador/validarInsertarMedico.php">
  <table width="42%" border="0" align="center">
    <tr bgcolor="#cc0000" class="texto">
      <td colspan="2" align="center">INSERTAR MEDICO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="28%" align="right" bgcolor="#fbec88">Identificación</td>
      <td width="72%"><label for="identificacion"></label>
      <input name="identificacion" type="text" id="identificacion" size="40"  required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" bgcolor="#fbec88">Nombres</td>
      <td><input name="nombres" type="text" id="nombres" size="40" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="25" align="right" bgcolor="#fbec88">Apellidos</td>
      <td><input name="apellidos" type="text" id="apellidos" size="40" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <tr>
      <td height="25" align="right" bgcolor="#fbec88">Especialidad</td>
      <td><input name="especialidad" type="text" id="espacialidad" size="40" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" bgcolor="#fbec88">Telefono</td>
      <td><input name="Telefono" type="text" id="Telefono" size="40" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" bgcolor="#fbec88">Correo</td>
      <td><input name="Correo" type="text" id="Correo" size="40" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#cc0000" class="texto">
      <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#cc0000"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Enviar" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

luego validar insertar medico

```
<?php
    session_start();
    extract($_REQUEST); //recoger todas las variables que pasan Método GET o POST
    require "../Modelo/conexionBasesDatos.php";
    require "../Modelo/Medico.php";
    //Creamos el objeto Paciente
    $objMedico= new Medico();
    $objMedico->CrearMedico($_REQUEST['identificacion'],$_REQUEST['nombres'],$_REQUEST['apellidos'],
    $_REQUEST['especialidad'],$_REQUEST['telefono'],$_REQUEST['correo']);

    $resultado = $objMedico->agregarMedico();
    if ($resultado)
        header ("location:index2.php?pag=insertarPaciente&msj=1");
    else
        header ("location:index2.php?pag=insertarPaciente&msj=2");

    ?>
```

y el archivo conexion base de datos

```
 <?php
 function Conectarse()
 {
    $objConexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","gue55me","centromedico");
    if ($objConexion->connect_errno)
    {
        echo "Erro de conexion a la Base de Datos ".$objConexion->connect_error;
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        return $objConexion;
    }
}
?>
```

Apreciaría su ayuda ya que el al ingresar al formulario no me esta enviando a la dirección correcta que es Controlador/validarInsertarMedico.php

Comment: Mi pregunta es en el formulario php tengo direccionado ../controlador/validarInsertarMedico.php pero me envia a ../vista/validarInsertarMedico.php que puedo hacer

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Para futuras preguntas, puedes identar el código seleccionando los bloques de código completos y luego pulsar sobre el icono `{ }` que aparece arriba. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Cuándo dices que se abre el archivo en la ruta `http://localhost/Vista/validarInsertarMedico.php`, cuando pulsas en el botón del formulario o cuándo?

Comment: ¿Hay algún tipo de validación o código JS que controle el formulario de alguna manera?

Comment: Buen día A. Cedano , si me dirige a la ruta que mencionaste pero el archivo esta en ../Controlador/validarInsertarMedico.php. bueno he movido el archivo a la ruta localhost/Vista/validarInsertarMedico.php funciona pero al insertar los datos del  medico , reviso la base de datos y solo me deja ingresar Identificacion , nombres y apellidos las otros datos quedan vacíos al dar click en enviar. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Alvaro , no hay codigo JS. Necesito uno ?por el momento soy algo nuevo en esto gracias por la ayuda. En el momento busco la forma de poder ingresar los datos a la base de datos en el servidor xammp

Comment: Gracias solucionado, el programa Xammp al cambiar archivos de ubicación solicita aceptar esa acción, el profesor deja errores en códigos que el envía es complicado encontrar errores Gracias! En Modelo.php estan los Gets y sets pero habían algunas variables que no estaban incluidas debí revisar ese archivo primero